# AngularJS child of child template not showing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-routing

No errors.

I'm able to access a list of teams at /teams and a specific team at /teams/2 where 2 is the id of a team.

```
  $stateProvider.state('app.teams.team', {
    url: '/:team',
    templateUrl: 'templates/teams/team.html',
    controller: 'TeamCtrl',
    resolve: {
      team: function($stateParams, TeamsService) {
        return TeamsService.getTeam($stateParams.team)
      }
    }
  })
```

I'm not able to access the roster at /teams/2/roster.

```
 $stateProvider.state('app.teams.team.roster', {
    url: '/roster',

    templateUrl: 'templates/teams/roster.html'

  })
```

The page loads without errors, and shows `templates/teams/team.html` instead of `templates/teams/roster.html`

Comment: Do you have a ui-view directive in team.html?

Comment: No, I don't.

I'm looking to override team.html with roster.html, am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you treat your states inheritance.

With the current configuration:

> app.teams.team state expect the url http://**app.teams url**/:team

and

> app.teams.team.roster state expect the url http://**app.teams.team url**/roster

each child expect the parent state to hold a ui-view directive so the templateUrl can get injected to.

This mean that for the roster state you have the app.teams htmls, contains the team html, contains the roster html.

To load a diffrent html under same level stay in same hirerchial level ->

> app.teams.team
>
> app.teams.roster

Comment: It's clear, but the issue is there's a different roster for each team and I need to be able to access it at teams/:team/roster.

I'm attempting to use a different state right now, app.roster with url: /teams/:team/roster and it seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making roster its own state, which works as intended.

```
  $stateProvider.state('app.roster', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/teams/:team/',
    views: {
      content: {
        template: '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>'
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      team: function($stateParams, TeamsService) {
        return TeamsService.getTeam($stateParams.team)
      }
    }

  })

  $stateProvider.state('app.roster.index', {
    url: 'roster',
    templateUrl: 'templates/roster/index.html',
    controller: 'TeamCtrl',
  })
```